# Android Open pdf file in browser using php

Tags: php, android, laravel, pdf, inline

I need to view (not download) a pdf file in the Android browser with PHP (and Laravel framework).
I have this piece of code:

```
return \Response::make(file_get_contents('/tmp/bg.pdf'), 200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'inline'; filename="final.pdf",
]);
```

This code works perfectly in desktop browser (i.e.Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera) but the code doesn't work in Android browser (Google Chrome).

Thanks.

Comment: Of course the problem is in the application if it works with browsers. 
Paste the Java snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) library. It is a JavaScript library created by mozilla and is use to view pdf file in the browser.